# Are there a lambda-mu expression equivalent to the yin yang puzzle?

Tags: lambda-calculus, continuations

The [yin yang puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694679/how-does-the-yin-yang-puzzle-work) was written in Scheme. Since it uses call/cc, it is not possible to express it in a pure lambda expression, unless we do a CPS transform.

However, given the fact that $\lambda \mu$-calculus have the power to model call/cc, is it possible to write an equivalent $\lambda \mu$-expression? I am still learning $\lambda \mu$-deductions, so this would be a good example to show how the deduction works.

There is no need to model the "display" command in a pure expression. Ideally only showing how the calculus keep looping and evaluates diffident terms again and again.

**UPDATE** My translation in $\lambda$-expression with CPS:

```
(λcallcc.callcc (λyin.callcc (λyang.yin yang))(λcc.cc cc)
```

In CPS, `(λcc.cc cc)` is what "call with current continuation" means. So the expression takes it as a parameter. This will result in assign the sub-expression starts `λyin` assign its continuation into parameter `yin`. And then in the body, the second callcc assigns the `yang` of sub-expression starts `λyang` into itself. Finally, apply `yin yang`.

Note the above translate is not full CPS, only the concept of call/cc has been translated. But it provides the same behavior and it is not hard to do a full CPS translate.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an important hint to solution by thinking how to make the yin-yang puzzle work in a typed language, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250474/does-the-yin-yang-continuations-puzzle-make-sense-in-a-typed-language). OCaml computes the type of `yin` and `yang` to be `('a -> 'a) as 'a`, which is a recursive type equal to its own function space. Such a type is precisely what it takes to implement the untyped $\lambda$-calculus in a typed language.

What does this have to do with your question? In the untyped $\lambda$-calculus (or typed calculus with general recursive types) we can *define* $\mu$ and other [fixed-point combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator). So, since `yin` and `yang` cannot be given types, we must use the untyped $\lambda$-calculus, but then $\mu$ is not needed as a primitive. In fact, the CPS transform of the puzzle will be just pure $\lambda$-calculus.

You can compute the CPS transform in the privacy of your mind. Here is my version, written in Ocaml. To run it, you need to pass `-rectypes` to Ocaml:

```
let callcc f k = f k ;;
let yin c = callcc (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> print_char '@'; c k) ;;
let yang c = callcc (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> print_char '*'; c k) ;;
let _  = yin yang (fun x -> x) ;;
```

Clearly, the `let` statements are just a convenience. Without them, and with `callcc` expanded out, we get:

```
(fun c -> (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> print_char '@'; c k))
(fun c -> (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> print_char '*'; c k))
(fun x -> x)
```

We could remove the `print_char` statement and $\eta$-reduce:

1. Start with:

   ```
   (fun c -> (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> c k))
   (fun c -> (fun x -> x x) (fun k -> c k))
   (fun x -> x)
   ```
2. Reduce `fun k -> c k` to `c`:

   ```
   (fun c -> (fun x -> x x) c) (fun c -> (fun x -> x x) c) (fun x -> x)
   ```
3. Reduce `fun c -> (fun x -> x x) c` to `fun x -> x x`:

   ```
   (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x x) (fun x -> x)
   ```

So the essence of the yin-yang puzzle is just self-application of self-application. How appropriate! As a last step, we can put in the `print_char` statements again, to get a one-liner:

```
(fun x -> x (fun k -> print_char '@'; x k)) (fun x -> x (fun k -> print_char '*'; x k)) (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: Is that you mean I don't need a λμ-expression? Can you please explain how to define μ since μ is not a "fixed-point combinator", as what I know so far.

Comment: I may have answered the wrong question because I totally assumed $\mu$ was a fixed point combinator. Are you referring to Parigot's $\lambda\mu$-calculus? In that case the answer ought to be similar, except we're not going to simulate continuations by explicit continuation passing, I suppose. The main point is that it's going to be untyped, no matter what you do.

Comment: I agreed that it is going to be untyped, and this is not what asking. But yes I am referring to Parigot's λμ-calculus so μ is not a fixed point combinator. I am learning it so I would like to see what the result looks like.

Comment: Well, you don't have to use $\mu$ because you can do it just with $\lambda$ (because we're untyped). Let me think what it would look like with $\mu$.

Comment: I said I understand that we can do the same thind with λ when using CPS. But CPS changes the semantic of the expression (your - an my - translated expression do not looks like or structured like the origin version any more), this is the reason why I am looking for a direct λμ translation.